# Github y carpeta secreta

Tags: github

Trabajo en un proyecto que comparto con otros desarrolladores. Como propietario del repositorio quiero controlar lo que los desarrolladores pueden ver y clonar.

Quiero tener una carpeta, dentro de la estructura de carpetas del proyecto, que solo yo pueda verla yo y que solo yo pueda pull/push/branch/merge/...

He probado el tema de los submodulos pero eso es un proyecto dentro de otro, no he visto que esta opción me pueda servir para evitar que alguien se pueda clonar la carpeta prohibida, hay comandos que permiten el clonado de todos los submodulos del proyecto.

Tambien he estado estudiando el comando Git subtree pero no he visto nada que pueda servirme. Sigue sin haber un control de accesos.

Una ayudita por favor....

Comment: he encontrado algo de contenido oculto: https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Hidden-file-contents/td-p/7908, supongo que si uno de los contenidos ocultos es una carpeta, eso resolvería tu problema

Comment: Creo que el enfoque de submódulos sería el único posible. El control de acceso debería ser a nivel del otro repositorio. Es decir, que el "sub-repositorio" sea privado y sólo tú tengas acceso a él. Cuando alguien intente clonar los submódulos, se le pediría la clave de acceso al otro repositorio y sin ella no podría clonarlo.